# Getting a SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not permitted

Tags: wireless

Hello I am totally new to this stuff . I am getting a `SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not permitted` error when I try to ifconfig wlan0 up.

Here are the before and after from my terminal.

```
root@bt:~# iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     unassociated  Nickname:"rtl_wifi"
          Mode:Auto  Access Point: Not-Associated   Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

eth0      no wireless extensions.


root@bt:~# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:4b:5c:be  
          inet addr:192.168.196.130  Bcast:192.168.196.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe4b:5cbe/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:124 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:38 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:11915 (11.9 KB)  TX bytes:3200 (3.2 KB)
          Interrupt:19 Base address:0x2000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:15 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:15 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:953 (953.0 B)  TX bytes:953 (953.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:02:72:3b:fe:45  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

root@bt:~# iwlist scan
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: 00:0D:97:07:E5:6E
                    ESSID:"<hidden>"
                    Protocol:IEEE 802.11bg
                    Mode:Master
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Encryption key:on
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s
                              48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Extra:wpa_ie=dd1a0050f20101000050f20202000050f2020050f20401000050f202
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    Extra:rsn_ie=30180100000fac020200000fac02000fac040100000fac020000
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    Signal level=42/100  
          Cell 02 - Address: C0:3F:0E:94:00:DE
                    ESSID:"Kenpoaksds"
                    Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
                    Mode:Master
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Encryption key:on
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Extra:rsn_ie=30140100000fac040100000fac040100000fac020c00
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD0E0050F204104A0001101044000102
                    Signal level=43/100  
          Cell 03 - Address: 28:28:5D:20:78:39
                    ESSID:"Fuji"
                    Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
                    Mode:Master
                    Frequency:2.452 GHz (Channel 9)
                    Encryption key:on
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Extra:wpa_ie=dd1c0050f20101000050f20202000050f2040050f20201000050f2020c00
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    Extra:rsn_ie=30180100000fac020200000fac04000fac020100000fac020c00
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F204104A00011010440001021049000600372A000120
                    Signal level=47/100  

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

root@bt:~# dmesg | tail
[   19.394752] acpiphp: Slot [62] registered
[   19.394846] acpiphp: Slot [63] registered
[   22.658036] eth0: no IPv6 routers present
[   23.280799] r8712u: CustomerID = 0x0000
[   23.280807] r8712u: MAC Address from efuse = 00:02:72:3b:fe:45
[   23.280812] r8712u: Loading firmware from "rtlwifi/rtl8712u.bin"
[   23.281497] usbcore: registered new interface driver r8712u
[   25.325874] r8712u: 1 RCR=0x153f00e
[   25.330997] r8712u: 2 RCR=0x553f00e
[   25.471834] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
root@bt:~# cd /usr/src/linux && cat .config | grep =i kill
grep: kill: No such file or directory
root@bt:/usr/src/linux# ifconfig wlan0 down
root@bt:/usr/src/linux# macchanger -m 00:11:22:33:44:55 wlan0
Current MAC: 00:02:72:3b:fe:45 (Cc&c Technologies, Inc.)
Faked MAC:   00:11:22:33:44:55 (Cimsys Inc)
root@bt:/usr/src/linux# ifconfig wlan0 up
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not permitted
root@bt:/usr/src/linux# iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     unassociated  Nickname:"rtl_wifi"
          Mode:Auto  Access Point: Not-Associated   Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

eth0      no wireless extensions.

root@bt:/usr/src/linux# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:4b:5c:be  
          inet addr:192.168.196.130  Bcast:192.168.196.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe4b:5cbe/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:254 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:39 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:23547 (23.5 KB)  TX bytes:3242 (3.2 KB)
          Interrupt:19 Base address:0x2000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:23 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:23 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1521 (1.5 KB)  TX bytes:1521 (1.5 KB)

root@bt:/usr/src/linux# iwlist scan
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

root@bt:/usr/src/linux# dmesg | tail
[   19.394752] acpiphp: Slot [62] registered
[   19.394846] acpiphp: Slot [63] registered
[   22.658036] eth0: no IPv6 routers present
[   23.280799] r8712u: CustomerID = 0x0000
[   23.280807] r8712u: MAC Address from efuse = 00:02:72:3b:fe:45
[   23.280812] r8712u: Loading firmware from "rtlwifi/rtl8712u.bin"
[   23.281497] usbcore: registered new interface driver r8712u
[   25.325874] r8712u: 1 RCR=0x153f00e
[   25.330997] r8712u: 2 RCR=0x553f00e
[   25.471834] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
root@bt:/usr/src/linux# cd /usr/src/linux && cat .config | grep =i kill
grep: kill: No such file or directory
root@bt:/usr/src/linux#
```

Comment: Why are you trying to fake your mac address?  Don't do that.